# Why does airflow have an SQS integration if it

Tags: etl, airflow, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to do ETL for messages on an SQS queue and airflow has an SQS integration (sensor) which makes me think that would be capable of constantantly polling SQS to run DAGs. However, that does not appear to be the case. The fastest it can run dags and poll for messages is once every few seconds, which does not work for the large quantity of data that I'm trying to consume.

I'm wondering why airflow has the SQS integration, or if it is even the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow is predominantly used for batch, or recurring processing on a relatively fixed schedule and isn't designed to do "live" processing. If your use case can be done in batches of, say 30 minutes, that may be more suited to Airflow.

Comment: Is there a tool that would be recommended over airflow?